# Summarizing Min values with multiple group by and filter conditions

Tags: dplyr

Need to calculate a min score for a combination of conditions including, missing, not missing, == 0, > 0). Getting a warning message min(score) no non missing arguments to min, returning Inf.

A spouse is determine when a sp_id > 0 or not missing integer variable
An owner is determined by ownership_percentage > 0 and not missing

By default a spouse with ownership_percentage  > 0 and not missing is an owner not a spouse

Created the test data to build a solution, have not been in R for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
    account_id <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    principal_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    contact_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    sp_id <-c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA,7)
    ownership_percentage <-c(25,0,NA,12,15,67,71)
    score <-c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,7)
    df <-data.frame(account_id,principal_id,contact_id,sp_id,ownership_percentage,score)
    
    View(df)
    
    # identify Non owner spouses(ownership_percentage = NA or 0) & (sp_id != NA or > 0) 
    # calculate min score
    df%>%
      group_by(account_id,principal_id,contact_id,sp_id) %>%
      filter(is.na(ownership_percentage) & ownership_percentage == 0 & (is.na(sp_id) || sp_id> 0)) %>%  
      summarise(min_score= min(score))
    
    View(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written your conditions are discarding all rows. Consider:

```r
is.na(ownership_percentage) & ownership_percentage == 0
```

this requires that `ownership_percentage` is **both** `NA` and `0`. No row can satisfy both these conditions, hence after your filter clause there are no rows left in the data set. This is what is causing the "no non missing arguments to min" warning message.

Perhaps what you intended was "is not NA". This is done using `!is.na(...)` for example:

```r
!is.na(ownership_percentage) & ownership_percentage == 0
```

The only difference is the exclamation mark at the start.

The same problem occurs for `is.na(sp_id) || sp_id> 0`.

As a general approach I would recommend creating indicator columns. Perhaps something like:

```r
step1 = df %>%
  mutate(is_spouse = ifelse(!is.na(sp_id) & sp_id > 0, 1, 0),
         is_owner = ifelse(!is.na(ownership_percentage) & ownership_percentage  > 0, 1, 0))
```

You can then inspect `stage1` to verify that these indicator columns appear as expected.

Once you are satisfied, you will likely find it clearer to give the command

```r
stage1 %>% filter(is_spouse == 1)
```

instead of

```r
stage1 %>% filter(!is.na(sp_id) & sp_id > 0)
```

Comment: started to go down this path Simon, TY for the look